# Nginx if cookie try_files rewrite

Tags: nginx, configuration

My website structure is that

`/public/index.php
/public/en.html
/public/zh_cn.html`

---

what i need to do?

- all request such as /user/login /user/home should be send to index.php except / /index /index/index.
- the / /index /index/index should be send to en.html if the cookie key lang is en, and if cookie key lang=zh_cn it should be send to zh_cn.html.if the cookie lang is empty then display en.html.

---

here are Nginx config:

```
location / {
index  index.php;
if ($http_cookie ~* "lang=en"){
    rewrite ^/$ /en.html;
    rewrite /index /en.html;
    rewrite /index/index /en.html;
}   
if ($http_cookie ~* "lang=zh_cn"){
    rewrite ^/$ /zh_cn.html;
    rewrite /index /zh_cn.html;
    rewrite /index/index /zh_cn.html;
}   

root    /www/wwwroot/public;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

}

but all request but / /index /index/index will return 404; i search in google and found that

> http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

```
  # try_files wont work due to if

    location /if-try-files {
         try_files  /file  @fallback;

         set $true 1;

         if ($true) {
             # nothing
         }
    }
```

that means if and try_files can't be used at same time,but i will be use if to test cookie value to decide use which html;

any other solution?

Comment: `try_files /$cookie_lang.html /en.html;`

Comment: thanks, but how to make the /user/login send to /index.php?q=/user/login.and  /index send to /$cookie_lang.html